# I need XSLT to filter XML by passing node values with pipe symbol

Tags: xslt, xml

My input xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
&lt;InfoReturn>
    &lt;LicenseInfo>
        &lt;licenseType>1&lt;/licenseType>
        &lt;licenseTypeDescAr>دائمة&lt;/licenseTypeDescAr>
        &lt;licenseTypeDescEn>Permanent&lt;/licenseTypeDescEn>
        &lt;centerId>1&lt;/centerId>
        &lt;centerNameA>مرور ديرة&lt;/centerNameA>
        &lt;centerNameE>TRAFFIC DEIRA&lt;/centerNameE>
        &lt;interimExpiryDate>2018-09-30T00:00:00.000Z&lt;/interimExpiryDate>
        &lt;licenseStatusArabic>مع المالك&lt;/licenseStatusArabic>
        &lt;licenseStatusEnglish>With Owner&lt;/licenseStatusEnglish>
        &lt;hasEyeTest>0&lt;/hasEyeTest>
        &lt;personId>1004257701&lt;/personId>
        &lt;isSpecialExpiryDesA>لا&lt;/isSpecialExpiryDesA>
        &lt;isSpecialExpiryDesE>NO&lt;/isSpecialExpiryDesE>
    &lt;/LicenseInfo>           
&lt;/InfoReturn>
```

Allowed fields will be passed as **centerId  |  centerNameE  |  personId**

The output XML which I am looking for is:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
&lt;InfoReturn>     
    &lt;LicenseInfo>
        &lt;centerId>1&lt;/centerId>
        &lt;centerNameE>TRAFFIC DEIRA&lt;/centerNameE>
        &lt;personId>1004257701&lt;/personId>
    &lt;/LicenseInfo>           
&lt;/InfoReturn>
```

Please provide XSLT for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3.0 this would simply be:

```
<xsl:param name="allowed-elements" as="xs:string" required="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="filter" as="xs:string*" 
              select="tokenize($allowed-elements, '\|') ! normalize-space()"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="LicenseInfo/*[not(name() = $filter)]"/>
```

Comment: The root element will always get change. Now it's licenseInfo and that could be some other value also. the input xml will always pass as a string.

Comment: If you want to supply more information about your requirements, please do that by editing your original question, not by commenting on answers.